Can not log in to Chrome Browser using Selenium Driver
I've tried to login with selenium on Chrome browser but I get the error:

Couldn’t sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.

System.setProperty("web.driver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe");   
    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys(email);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'identifierNext\']/div/button/span")).click();

driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys(password);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'passwordNext\']/div/button/span")).click();


Warning: Automating login into Google accounts violates the terms and conditions of Google so its not recommended to automate the login process for obvious security reasons. However if you are using a test account and still want to automate it then you can can use Chrome options as shown in the code.
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");//this would help bypass bot detection by Chrome
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys(email);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'identifierNext\']/div/button/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'passwordNext\']/div/button/span")).click();

This might not work all the time as Google might improve its detection mechanism for automation frameworks like Selenium
